# How to grab database URI from config object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In [python101](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter34_sqlalchemy.html)  the URI for the database in declared in the `models.py` file but I would like to use the one declared in the app configuration file and not import the config class and creating a new object and accessing the Uri from that object
`models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mymusic.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class Artist(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "artists"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

`config.py`

```
class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///database.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class Debug(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class Prod(Config):
    DEBUG = False

config = {
    'dev': Debug,
    'prod': Prod
}
```

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask 
from config import config
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config['dev'])
```

How do you use the database uri declared in `config.py`  in models without creating an new `Config` object and retrieving the uri

Answer (score 0):

## Class Variables vs Instance Variables

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` and `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` are **not** varibles of objects of the class `Config`, they are variables of the class itself.

You do not have to create an object of the class to access the class variable.

```py
from config import Config

database_uri = Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

## Flask Config

You can access the app's config from anywhere with

```
from flask import current_app

value = current_app.config.get('key')
```

I suppose key would be `'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'` or `'DATABASE_URI'`.

Comment: what if i am running a function as a daemon thread and need to access the config, isn't that going to throw an error about `app_context`